# SSRS 2008 R2 Remove White Space if Null

Tags: ssrs-2008, suppression, ifnull

I have a simple SQL Server 2008 R2 report with a textbox containing a few fields. I want to suppress the line if the value of a field is null. What would be the syntax for the expression?

So my fields are...

```
Name
AddressLine1
AddressLine2
AddressLine3
CityStateZip
```

and I have expressions like this...

```
=First(Fields!AddressLine2.Value, "dsPersonData")
```

I was trying the expression below but getting errors

```
=IIF(Fields!AddressLine2.Value, "",True,False)
```

In other words I was trying to set the visibility to false if the value was an empty string but I'm not sure what the syntax would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is easy to do this in the sql query, For example:

in SQL Server:

ISNULL(Name, '') as Name
ISNULL(AdressLine1, '') as AdressLine1
ISNULL(AdressLine2, '') as AdressLine2
ISNULL(AdressLine3, '') as AdressLine3
ISNULL(CityStateZip, '') as CityStateZip

and if you want to set the visibility to false:
=IIF(First(Fields!AddressLine2.Value, "dsPersonData") = "",False,True)

Comment: Thanks, I think I can use this to get my result.

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
=IIF(First(Fields!AddressLine2.Value, "dsPersonData") is Nothing ,False,True)
```